# Remove non-existing records from xrandr

Tags: multiple-monitors, xrandr

I lost my connection to a third monitor about a month ago for unknown reason. I've been waiting if some update would fix it, but it seems to be a persistent problem. I need help.

Environment: basic ubuntu 18.04 installation. Dell laptop with TB16 Dock.

I noticed that my `xrandr` shows multiple monitors that do not seem to exists. The laptop has only a connector for one external HDMI display. I guess this might be related to the problem (maybe I connected my laptop to some external third display that screwed up some settings).

I tried to remove the `~/.config/monitors.xml`, but that did not have an effect on the `xrandr` output. Is there a way to remove or reset the xrandr monitor database?

xrandr output when disconnected from the Dock:

```
 $ xrandr|grep connect
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 173mm
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

xrandr output when connected from the Dock:

```
 $ xrandr|grep connect
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+2160 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 173mm
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1-2 connected 3840x2160+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 609mm x 349mm
DP-1-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

When I disconnect the working external display from the Dock, the disconnected monitor (hd) starts working and it is show in the xrandr on the same name as the previous monitor:

```
 $ xrandr|grep connect
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 173mm
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1-2 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 527mm x 296mm
DP-1-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8713/85695). Instead, paste the text directly into your question and use the [formatting tools](//askubuntu.com/help/formatting) to format it as code.

Comment: yeah ok. I replaced the images with copy-paste.

Comment: Thanks! I doubt these are relevant though. It ism't listing screens, it's listing available screen connectors. Your output looks normal to me.

Comment: As a workaround, I connected the third monitor to the HDMI-connector in the laptop. It seems like I'm not able to use two monitors through the thunderbolt TB16 dock. Maybe the 4k@60hz requires too much bandwidth to allow another monitor to be connected.